# Reading a XML File in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I am importing a XML file that has an amount field `<amount>$10.00</amount>` but when it is read in using code I got from your other posts, the value is returned as `.00`.

Using:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("testInput.xml");
print_r($xml);
```

Result:

```
[amount] => .00
```

I can't find anywhere why this is failing... Unless it has to do with the `$` or period in the value field but I can't find anything about reserved characters.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to duplicate your results and couldn't...

I created a file called xml_test.php:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test_input.xml');
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Then built the XML (test_input.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
  <test>
    <amount>$10.00</amount>
  </test>
</tests>
```

And this was my result in the browser:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [test] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [amount] => $10.00 ) )
```

Is there anything else going on or am I missing something?  Maybe you can paste in your XML...